# Cassandra duplicate keys in map

Tags: collections, cassandra, hashmap, cassandra-3.0

Is Cassandra map implementation Map or MultiMap? In other words, does Cassandra allow duplicate keys in map type? Based on [this example](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useInsertMap.html), if I called

```
UPDATE cycling.cyclist_teams SET teams = teams + {2009 : 'First team'} WHERE id = 5b6962dd-3f90-4c93-8f61-eabfa4a803e2;
```

and then

```
UPDATE cycling.cyclist_teams SET teams = teams + {2009 : 'Second team'} WHERE id = 5b6962dd-3f90-4c93-8f61-eabfa4a803e2;
```

then database would look like this: A)

```
teams[2009]: 'Second team'
```

or this: B)

```
teams[2009]: 'First team'
teams[2009]: 'Second team'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useMap.html) is very clear on this:

> A map relates one item to another with a key-value pair. For each key, only one value may exist, and duplicates cannot be stored. Both the key and the value are designated with a data type.

That is, the value will be overwritten, just as is the case with a java HashMap. The result will be `{2009 : 'Second team'}`

Comment: just to clarify: it could be the `{2009: 'First team'}` if client's clocks are not synchronized...